# Difference between GridFs and GridFile

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

As i read on the "gridfs.h" file

> A GridFS represents a single collection of GridFS files in the
>   database.
>
> A GridFile is a single GridFS file.

For Example: I have six files...so as per my understanding i can store them in one single GridFS with 6 Girdfile? (Make me right if i am wrong).
Can anyone please explain the difference between GridFs and Gridfile in much more easy way?..Sorry for my little understanding about these two.

Answer (score 0):

Only a single opened GridFile instance may exist for a file in gridfs at any time.
Its lik an api call to manage gridfs's..!
Refer [api.mongodb.org/python/1.3/api/gridfs/grid_file.html](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.3/api/gridfs/grid_file.html)